# Press ESC to close popup window for Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have this function for closing popup window by pressing the `ESC` escape key. However it is not working for Google Chrome. I don't know what is missing; does anyone have a solution ?

```
function doClose(e) 
{
    if (!e) e = window.event; 

    if (e.keyCode) 
    {
        if (e.keyCode == "27") window.close();
    }
    else if (e.charCode) 
    {
        if (e.keyCode == "27") window.close();
    }
}
document.onkeypress = doClose;
```

Comment: Should the second one be if (e.charCode === "27")?

Comment: You can put that all in one line with `if ((e.keyCode || e.charCode)  =='27' )`

Answer (score 3):

onkeypress does not capture some keys - mainly system keys like ESC and F1 -> F12, use onkeydown instead. Also there's a bug in your logic, update to:

```
function doClose(e) 
{
    if (!e) e = window.event; 

    if (e.keyCode) 
    {
        if (e.keyCode == "27") window.close();
    }
    else if (e.charCode) 
    {
        if (e.charCode == "27") window.close();
    }
}
document.onkeydown = doClose;
```

Answer (score 0):

Google Chrome bug:

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=9061

to WebKit Bug:

https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=25147